# python functools.partial with fixed array valued argument

Tags: python, function, vectorization

I'm trying to vectorize the following function over the argument `tiling`:

```
def find_tile(x,tiling):
    """
    Calculates the index of the closest element of 'tiling' to 'x'.
    tiling: array of grid positions
    x: variable of the same type as the elements of tiling
    """
    return np.argmin(np.linalg.norm(tiling - x, axis=1))
```

For instance, the non-vectorized version of the function can accept the following arguments

```
tiling = np.array( [[i,j] for i in xrange(3) for j in xrange(3)] )
x = np.array([1.2, 2.7])
```

I'm interested in finding the fastest possible vectorisation, such that `x` remains a single vector and I can pass a list of arguments `tiling`

So I tried defining multiple tilings using a generator:

```
tilings = (tiling + np.random.uniform(0,1,2)  for j in xrange(3))
```

and then using `map` and `functools.partial`:

```
map(functools.partial(find_tile, x=x), tilings)
```

Apparently, there's a problem with `x` being an array or something, since I'm getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 43, in <module>
    inds = map(functools.partial(find_tile, x=x), ts)
TypeError: find_tile() got multiple values for keyword argument 'x'
```

Can someone explain to me how to get around it?

Also, is there an alternative and faster way to do this (possibly re-writing the function `find_tile`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing in `x` as a *keyword argument*. `map()` passes in each element from `tilings` in as a *positional argument*. However, since your first positional argument is `x`, that clashes with the keyword argument. Using a name as a keyword argument does not prevent that same name being filled with a positional argument.

Don't use a keyword argument for `x`; just pass it in as a positional argument to `partial()`:

```
map(functools.partial(find_tile, x), tilings)
```

Now each element from `tilings` is passed in as the second positional argument and the call works.